# aaply for data.table to find length of intersection of interval

Tags: r, date, data.table, posixct

I have data like this:

```
View(dose_merged)

    SUBJECT_Blinded PACKID  SACDPDAT    SACRTDAT    treatment_interval  SD_SDAT     SD_EDAT
1   1501301         10094   2012-05-26  2012-07-23  58                  2012-01-03  2013-01-02
2   1601301         10555   2012-01-03  2012-01-31  28                  2012-01-03  2013-01-0
```

With columns types in data table:

```
> mapply(class, dose_merged)
$SUBJECT_Blinded
[1] "numeric"

$PACKID
[1] "numeric"

$SACDPDAT
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$SACRTDAT
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$treatment_interval
[1] "Interval"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"

$SD_SDAT

[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$SD_EDAT
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I want to determine the length of intersection of intervals: interval(SACDPDAT, SACRTDAT) and interval(SD_SDAT, SD_EDAT).
I am trying this:

```
dose_merged[,intersect1 := aaply(dose_merged, 1, function(x){intersect(interval(x[3],x[4]),      interval(x[8],x[9]))})]
```

But then I get error message:

```
Error: error while computing 'x' when choosing method for 'intersect': Error in as.POSIXct.default(start) : 
  do not know how to convert 'start' to class “POSIXct”
```

The line

```
intersect(interval(x[3],x[4]), interval(x[8],x[9]))})
```

works for specified row x.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

The first two rows of dput(dose_merge):

```
structure(list(SUBJECT_Blinded = c(1101001, 1101001), PACKID = c(10096, 
10595), SACDPDAT = structure(c(1335304800, 1325545200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SACRTDAT = structure(c(1340316000, 1327964400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), treatment_interval = structure(c(58, 
28), class = structure("Interval", package = "lubridate")), TS_SDAT = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TS_EDAT = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SD_SDAT = structure(c(1325545200, 
1325545200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SD_EDAT = structure(c(1357081200, 
1357081200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("SUBJECT_Blinded", 
"PACKID", "SACDPDAT", "SACRTDAT", "treatment_interval", "TS_SDAT", 
"TS_EDAT", "SD_SDAT", "SD_EDAT"), sorted = "SUBJECT_Blinded", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002f30788>)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your data ( the output of `dput(dose_merged)`). (otherwise we have to work out how to create columns of class "interval"

Comment: It's hard for me to post original data because is real data and I should not make it public. However, I can produce some examples.

Comment: As I said, I can produce something similiar, of course. However, I don't know if it would help because the column $treatment_interval does not play any role in the piece of code I've presented. To sum up - I can provide you with this data, tell me if it would really help with anything :)

Comment: surely you can provide the first two rows `dputted` (the data you've give us already)

Comment: OK, I've already added the first two rows of dputted.